# How do I save the images docker downloads in the home partition instead of root in Ubuntu? And how do I move them out of root to home?

Tags: docker

My root partition is full already and these images are huge. So I need urgently a way to do that. At least until the semester is over and I can afford to shift around the partitions in my disk.

Edit: can an admin move my question?

Comment: We don't know what release you are using, nor what size you allocated (Ubuntu Desktops recommends 25GB as the minimum, and has done so for all releases starting with 17.10 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements), so a recommended fix maybe increasing the size of your partition. You can move data via a *live* system, then change your *file system table* to reflect new changes.. but a starting point is the OS you're using which currently is unknown.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, 27GB partition for root. It was upgraded from 16.04. I can move the partition in fact I plan to delete de windows partition and do that but I can't afford to screw something up while my semester from college is ending still. Later it's all right

Comment: You can `mount` directories to any drive/partition/device, and your `fstab` (*file system table*) tells the system where it all is... If for example /blah you decided was chewing all your space, you could boot the *live* system, I would copy (`rsync`/`cp`/ etc) the /blah directory to its new device/location, `diff` to compare which is optional but I do it; note: I didn't `mv`) then change `/etc/fstab` to point to that new location. I'd likely create a file via touch there for validation (`touch blah`). Boot & verify all looks good, you can see `blah` and all works...

Comment: If all looks okay, you can reboot to *live* system and remove the original directory contents (/blah/ must remain as an empty directory), and now have the some free space.  If you mount another directory **over** a directory that existed; it'll *shadow* (as in hide) the first directory - thus allowing some *testing* of what you did.. This is what I'd do, but I don't use docker, so don't know what directories you'll need to move... if you want more, you'll have to wait for a user to write an answer properly (or some upticks that may show others agree with these comments; which are done quickly)